# sailsjs / waterline query "where" not empty

Tags: sails.js, waterline

Hy there,

Before going to the hacky / cutom way i wanted to know if there is a built in `query` way to check for an empty / non empty  many to many relationship as i was not successfull neither on google nor the doc.

If i take the example in the doc let's imagine i want to retrive a user only if he has a a Pet or Retrive a Pet without any Owner through a query.

```
// A user may have many pets
var User = Waterline.Collection.extend({

  identity: 'user',
  connection: 'local-postgresql',

  attributes: {
    firstName: 'string',
    lastName: 'string',

    // Add a reference to Pet
    pets: {
      collection: 'pet',
      via: 'owners',
      dominant: true
    }
  }
});

// A pet may have many owners
var Pet = Waterline.Collection.extend({

  identity: 'pet',
  connection: 'local-postgresql',

  attributes: {
    breed: 'string',
    type: 'string',
    name: 'string',

    // Add a reference to User
    owners: {
      collection: 'user',
      via: 'pets'
    }
  }
});
```

P.s. i know how to filter results after query execution that's not what i'm asking :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is nothing built in (aka User.hasPet() ) or something like that., so the simple answer is NO**

If I know of these issues before hand I tend to write my DB in such a way that the queries are fast. IE: the User schema would have a hasPets column. Whenever a pet is added/removed a callbacks hits the user table to mark that field if it has an owner or not. So then I can query User.findAll({hasPet:true}).

Its a little much, but it depends on where you speed is needed.

Comment: Hy, thx for your answer i would add it to one of the "hacky" way :) i've also heard that some Adapters have a Model.query("putyournativesqlhere"). In my case for the moment i just run a ".filter" function after the query completion. I think waterlines misses a sort of "WQL" (waterline query language :)) but it's still a young orm so let's wait a bit :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit late, but I wanted to let you know it's pretty easy to do this with the Waterline ORM lifecycle functions.  I've done it in a few of my projects.  Basically, use the beforeCreate and beforeUpdate functions to set your flags.  For your user, it might look like...

```
 var User = Waterline.Collection.extend({

  identity: 'user',
  connection: 'local-postgresql',

  beforeCreate: function(values, next) {
    if (values.pets) {
      values.has_pet = true;
    } else {
      values.has_pet = false;
    }
    next();
  }

  beforeUpdate: function(values, next) {
    if (values.pets) {
      values.has_pet = true;
    } else {
      values.has_pet = false;
    }
    next();
  }

  attributes: {
    firstName: 'string',
    lastName: 'string',

    // Add a reference to Pet
    pets: {
      collection: 'pet',
      via: 'owners',
      dominant: true
    },

    has_pet: {
      type: 'boolean'
    }
  }
});
```

Then you can query based on the has_pet attribute

Comment: Hy, thanks for your reply, i consider it as part of the Hacky way ;)